# How to rotate, resize and zoom an image from corners in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on a collage application. I want this type of effect in my images while making a collage. 
http://lesterflor.com/HTML5/CanvasExample/index.html

I want to rotate and resize the image from a particular point on mouse down.

He has used YUI. Is there any other possible method or plugin to get the same effect using `Javascript`? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

for resize just modify heigh and width like $("#imgID").attr("width","400px");

for rotation use CSS (webkit):

-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); //angle

-webkit-transform-origin:mouseX mouseY 0; //Point to rotate around

U can modify it with jquery too.

---

Jquery libary: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html

but i dont know if u can set the point to rotate around!